# Internet connection disruption every few seconds

Tags: networking, internet, ping

A few months ago I started experiencing an issue with my connection which hasn't gone away. 
Every day at seemingly random times my internet connection starts behaving strangely. Every ~15 seconds the connection is just gone, which lasts ~10 seconds, then it's back up again. I've done a few ping tests by pinging google and the issue becomes visible. While the connection is down, the command prompt displays a "Request has timed out" message. Sometimes I also get massive ping spikes, not a complete stoppage. The wifi from the same router is experiencing the same thing on my phone.

I've tried almost everything at this point, restarting both the router and modem multiple times remotely and manually, reset to factory settings, did some CMD commands, checked my internet cable, even had a router change recently and still no improvements. My modem is pretty old though. Could it be an issue with my ISP? I have some screenshots of the ping tests can't post them yet.

Comment: Feel free to include links to the screenshots and we can link them in for you (or better, the plain text).

Comment: What is your connection? (Cable / xDSL)... Have you checked the modem / router to determine if the connection is dropping, and why that might be? (more specific questions can follow when we know what type of connection you have)

Comment: Have you tried using an Ethernet connection. This would determine if the issue is WIFI related (which would be my guess)